# Anonymize short links

Tags: script, posts, hyperlinks

“Share” links under questions and answers include one's UserId, which may not be desirable for those who want to keep separate online identities at SE and elsewhere. ([Pointed out at Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300472).)

This simple script removes the UserId from "share" links.
Tested in Chrome with Tampermonkey.

- [Source code at GitHub](https://github.com/normalhuman/CustomSE/blob/master/anonymizeShare.user.js)
- [Direct installation link from GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/normalhuman/CustomSE/master/anonymizeShare.user.js)

Comment: The current script will fail to act on dynamically loaded posts (new, pagination, etc.)  Use an AJAX-aware technique (Timer, `waitForKeyElements`, Mutation Observer, etc.) to handle those.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the links to the source and install website went dead. I'm keeping this for reference in case someone else gets inspired by this and creates a new fresh script or app.