# Optionally Anonymised Short Links

Tags: script, hyperlinks

### Description

This is a resurrection of the (now no longer accessible) UserScript [Anonymize short links](https://stackapps.com/q/6507).

Specifically, this script implements [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300647) by adding a checkbox ([toggle switch](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/toggle-switch/)) to each share [popover](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/popovers/).

When installing the UserScript, by default, there are no changes to behaviour. It does add a toggle button that allows you to set your preference:

[image: share popover from this stackapps question displaying link that contains a user id. Below the share link is an added toggle button "Include User Id" which is "checked" and green.]

This toggle is used to both remove (or add) the user id from the share link, but also to set your network-wide preference. The UserScript saves this preference using `GM_getValue` and retrieves it using `GM_setValue`, for this reason only UserScript managers that support these operations are supported.

[image: share popover from this stackapps question displaying link that does not contain a user id. Below the share link is an added toggle button "Include User Id" which is not "checked" and is grey.]

At any time you are able to copy the opposite link without needing to change your preferences by clicking the copy button to the right of the toggle.

### Installation

1. Install a UserScript manager that supports `GM_getValue` and `GM_setValue`
2. Add the UserScript to your manager [install link](https://github.com/HenryEcker-SO-UserScripts/SO-UserScripts/raw/main/AnonymousShareLinks.user.js) ([GitHub Source](https://github.com/HenryEcker-SO-UserScripts/SO-UserScripts/blob/main/AnonymousShareLinks.user.js))

Comment: This looks very nice. But did you have to copy Stacks' horrible style of not rendering initialisms like "ID" in all caps?

Comment: I guess it really should be all lowercase to match the subtitle "(Includes your user id)". :P

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Add a button to copy the anonymized link regardless of the persistent preference. It is very plausible that the user would like to make a one-time copy of an anonymized link without actually changing the preference (or vice versa for that matter).

Adding a separate button should not require significant development effort as it could simply reuse the existing logic. As a quick mockup, it could look like this:

[image: a mockup of the "share" popover with an "Anon copy" button added to the right of the "Copy link" button]

Comment: This is now done in both directions. Slightly different UI (screenshots updated in the question), but both types of links are now always accessible regardless of preference for one-time copy purposes.

Comment: @HenryEcker cool, thanks :) Yeah, even better the way you did it - I just made a quick mockup to illustrate - like the dynamic switching between states.